# Php cannot access attributes of an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an array of objects of this form,

```
[{value => 1, name => "Ha"},
{value => 2, name => "Hi"},
{value => 3, name => "Ho"},
.....]
```

and a function that should return the value given a certain name,

the function is:

```
public function get_value_from_name($myArray, $name){
$arrays = $myArray;

    foreach ($arrays as $arr){
    if ($name == $arr->name){
        return $arr->value;
      }
    }
    return false;
    }
 }
```

when I use the function and pass it the array and a string this way 
get_value_from_name($myArray, "Hi")
I expect getting a 2 but it returns false,
I tried tracing the results, the foreach loops through the whole array but I think that $arr->name doesn't give anything, I am not sure. 
Can you check if something is wrong with my function, I am new to PHP.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT ********** UPDATE:**
That's what I get when debugging

```
public function get_value_from_name($arr, $names){ //$arr: {[2], [2], [2], [2] + 72 more} $names: "Hi"

$arrays = $arr; //{ $arrays: {[2], [2], [2], [2] + 72 more}
  foreach ( $arrays as $array ){ // $arrays: {[2], [2], [2], [2] + 72 more} $array: {value => 79, name => "HiHiHiHiHiHi"}[2]
     if ( $array->name ==  $names) //{$names: "Hi"
     return $array->value; 
     }
  }
return false;
}
```

***My Solution* :**
I managed to make it work this way, But can someone explain why the first function did not work,

```
public function get_id_from_name($arr, $names){
$arrays = $arr;

$nameArray = array_column($arrays, 'name');
$valueArray = array_column($arrays, 'value');

 foreach (array_combine($valueArray, $nameArray) as $value=> $name) {
   if ($name == $names) {
   return $value;
 }
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in code. Its should:

```
...    
    foreach ($arrays as $arr){
      if ($name == $arr->name){
        return $arr->value;
      }
    } // this is mistake
    return false;
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the function was:
 
    foreach ($arrays as $arr){
        if ($name == $arr->name){
            return $arr->value;
         }
       } 
       return false;

I typed the code instead of coying pasting it so should it be working ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way,

```
<?php
$obj = array();
$obj1 = new stdClass();
$obj1->value = 1;
$obj1->name = 'Ha';
$obj2 = new stdClass();
$obj2->value = 2;
$obj2->name = 'Hi';
$obj3 = new stdClass();
$obj3->value = 3;
$obj3->name = 'Ho';
$obj = [$obj1,$obj2,$obj3];

function get_value_from_name($arrays, $name){
    foreach ($arrays as $arr){
     if ($name == $arr->name){
        return $arr->value;
     }
   }
 }

 echo get_value_from_name($obj,'Ho');
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/TkjGe

Comment: Even When I take off the return false it's not working and In think it should be working with both, 
I have added a snip on the results of the debugging if that helps. It is reaching the end of the loop without finding any match

Comment: that is because $names='Hi' doesn't match with any of your nested object's name

Comment: the value: 26 has a name: 'Hi'

Comment: seems your array of object is not same that you are saying, Did you checked my demo, it should work for any length ?

Comment: You're missing `{` after you `foreach` also. Please check my given snippet of code properly

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work with this function, can someone explain why the first one didn't work:

```
public function get_id_from_name($arr, $names){
$arrays = $arr;

$nameArray = array_column($arrays, 'name');
$valueArray = array_column($arrays, 'value');

 foreach (array_combine($valueArray, $nameArray) as $value=> $name) {
   if ($name == $names) {
   return $value;
 }
}
return false;
}
```